# Bigquery count over multiple values and aggregate

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery

I am one Week into BQ now (for my Master Thesis) and after many hours of reading docs I am now hanging at this point:

I use the censys Datasets and want to count the number of hosts with ports  open in country 'AT', 'DE', 'CH'. So far I got it working for each country itself. But so save Costs (maybe) I want to count it for all 3 countries at once. Or when I can't save costs with this approach I can stay with my first solution and iterate over it for every country.

Currently working for one Country at a time:

```
#standardsql
SELECT ports, count(ports) AS value FROM
(
SELECT ip, ports
FROM `censys-io.ipv4_public.20171231` i, i.ports
WHERE location.country_code LIKE 'AT'
)
GROUP BY ports
```

Trying to combine all countries:

```
#standardsql
SELECT location.country_code, ports, count(ports) OVER ( PARTITION BY location.country_code) AS value FROM
(
SELECT location.country_code, ports 
FROM `censys-io.ipv4_public.20171231` i, i.ports
WHERE location.country_code LIKE 'AT', 'DE', 'CH'
)
GROUP BY ports
```

It gives me (when i ignore the WHERE error in 6):

```
 Error: Unrecognized name: location at [2:8]
```

Given the proposed Answer here a screenshot from the error with schema included:
[image]

I dont know if this is the right way to do it, or if I should use other functions.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see multiple problems with your queries.  You appear to be doing an implicit join between two tables.  Is this intended?  I also don't think you need to be using a subquery here.

Comment: It's only one Table. I am open for a simpler solution if there is one. Basically I need the Data for all 3 Countries which i can then download as json to work with. Maybe I need to mention that "ports" is an Array. So i need the Subquery to unnest it.

Comment: I also want to mention that location is a Record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it now:

```
#standardsql
SELECT 
  country_code, 
  ports, 
  COUNT(ports) AS value FROM
(
SELECT location.country_code, ports 
FROM `censys-io.ipv4_public.20171231` i, i.ports
WHERE location.country_code IN ('AT', 'DE', 'CH')
)
GROUP BY ports, country_code
```

Deleted the PARTITION BY.

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardsql
SELECT 
  country_code, 
  ports, 
  COUNT(ports) OVER ( PARTITION BY country_code, ports) AS value FROM
(
SELECT location.country_code, ports 
FROM `censys-io.ipv4_public.20171231` i, i.ports
WHERE location.country_code IN ('AT', 'DE', 'CH')
)
GROUP BY country_code, ports
```

Comment: Close, it gives me a list of countries and ports, but the value is always 1.

Can you tell me why i have to select country_code and not location.country_code?

Comment: When you output record's field without explicitly providing alias - BigQuery assigns name of that field as an alias. As of "always 1" - as you can see I added ports into `PARTITION BY` statement as I thought it makes more sense - but I don't know nature of your data so it is hard to comment on this

Comment: Thanks i will look into the help pages, and thanks for your hint to the solution! :D

Comment: @dr.gruselglatz You also get points if you mark an answer correct, besides the other beneficial side effects.